# Elitebook HP 8570p keyboard upgrade

Tags: keyboard

I'm owner of the old HP Elitebook 8570p. It's perfect but the keyboard backlit is missing in this model. I am wondering if it is possible to do swap keyboard from workstation version (8570w).I know that may be some risk with that operation, but anyway I accept it.

1. I would like to buy 8570w keyboard version
2. Then put it into my 8570p laptop
3. Make custom DIY microsupply power adapter (maybe using USB) if necessary to make keyboard backlit possible

Will this keyboard fit into my model (even after some mods).
Is it possible? :) Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: In principle this should be possible of course, but perhaps not for less money than a new backlit laptop costing € 290 would be, the Acer 575 comes to mind.